# How to fix "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" on bcrypt.hashpw

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlite, bcrypt

I am setting up a server, and on my login page I use bycrpt's hashpw function to hash the passwords before storing them in the database. When I click login, I get the error message "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" I have tried encoding the passwords before hashing them both with .encode() and .encdoe('utf-8') in multiple locations and times.

This is a copy of Windows Server 2019 (on an AWS EC2 instance), running Python 3.7 and Sqlite3. This was running fine for a while, and when I changed computers, it stopped working.

This is my code for the login page:

```
def loginpage():
    global error
    if request.method == "POST":
        usrname = request.form['username']
        pswd = request.form['password']
        if not db.checkExists(usrname):
            error = "Invalid username or password!"
        elif not db.checkValidUser(usrname, pswd.encode('utf-8')):
            error = "Invalid username or password!"
        else:
            session['loggedIn'] = True
            session['user'] = request.form['username']
            if session.get('prevurl') == None:
                return redirect(url_for('index'))
            else:
                prev = session.get('prevurl')
                session['prevurl'] = ''
                return redirect(url_for(prev))
    return render_template('login.html', **globals())
```

And this is my database handler code:

```
def checkValidUser(username, password):
    #get salt and hash passwords
    if not checkExists(username):
        return False
    salt = getSalt(username)
    salt = salt[0][0]
    #password = password.encode('utf-8')
    password = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt)
    #connect to database
    con = sql.connect(sqlite_db_file)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?", (username, password))
    validUser = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()

    if not validUser:
        return False
    return True
```

When I click login, I should either see an error saying "Incorrect username or password" or get redirected to the main page while being logged in. Instead I get a typeError telling me that unicode objects must be encoded. If you know something that could help, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Try encoding salt.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Debendra, but I seem to have solved the issue. The error has gone away and signing in works properly, I just do not know what I did. When I next encounter this error I will try this suggestion and see if it works. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the issue is related to the differences between `bcrypt` and `py-bcrypt` as discussed [here on github](https://github.com/pythonanywhere/help_pages/issues/6).

Those are different modules. `bcrypt` expects bytes (encoded strings), `py-bcrypt` expets strings (`str`). So if you don't want to change your code, you'd have to install `py-bcrypt`.

I'm not certain whether it has the same feature set.